# what does the percent sign do in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Other than as a modulus operator, what does the percent sign do in PHP?

For instance, I am looking at some PHP code, and see the following:

```
define('TABLE_PREFIX','%CONFIG-PREFIX');
```

Elsewhere, in a SQL file, I see the following.  I expect the SQL script is being parsed by PHP.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `%TABLE_PREFIX%api_key`;
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it does anything special in the string. Maybe the library you're using modifies it somehow?

Comment: as to sql its usually a wild card "% Matches any number of characters, even zero characters" but this case its something 'custom"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't intrinsically treat it specially within strings. It must be the application that's parsing the strings and deciding that `%` indicates some kind of variable value.

In fact, it looks like you're looking at the source code of a project called [osTicket](http://www.osticket.com). In its installer, I found this line which corresponds to your given define:

```
$configfile= str_replace('%CONFIG-PREFIX',$_POST['prefix'],$configfile);
```

Comment: Your right about osticket.  I had also found the below script listed under nickb's post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, nothing. Somewhere in whatever database driver you're using, the driver is parsing that string to put the prefix in, most likely with something similar to:

```
$sql = str_replace( '%TABLE_PREFIX%', TABLE_PREFIX, $sql);
```

Comment: Found it.  Thanks!

function replace_table_prefix($query) {
    return str_replace('%TABLE_PREFIX%',PREFIX, $query);
}